# Need assistance on blackjack python project implementing hit/stand feature

Tags: python, blackjack

im just working on a blackjack project and im new to coding so its a little tough trying to add new functions such as the hit/stand function. I have tried making a hit/stand function but im not sure how to actually add a new card to the total of the players cards and the dealer also. im just staring by adding the players to try and get some result but a am just stuck at this rate and have no idea how i can properly implement this. I have a sep file that stores the list of the deck and shuffle but is imported

```
import playing_cards
import random
player_hand = []
dealers_hand = []
hands = [[]]



#STAGE 1 - testing purpose only

# Testing code for step 1 
##card = playing_cards.deal_one_card()
##print(card)




#Stage 2 - testing purpose only   (PLAYERS HAND)

# Deal first card
card = playing_cards.deal_one_card()

# Append it to the player_hand list
player_hand.append(card)
# Deal second card
card = playing_cards.deal_one_card()
# Append it to the player_hand list
player_hand.append(card)
#ADDING UP BOTH CARDS

# Display the player's hand to the screen using a simple print statement
#print("Player's hand is ",  player_hand)


#Stage 4 and 5

suits = {'C': 'Club', 'H': 'Heart', 'D': 'Diamond', 'S': 'Spade'}
names = {'2': '2', '3': '3', '4': '4', 
            '5':'5', '6': '6', '7': '7', '8': '8', '9': '9', 'T': '10','J': 'Jack', 'Q': 'Queen', 'K': 'King', 'A': 'Ace'}


def score_hand(player_hand):
  " Scores hand with adjustment for Ace "
  value = {}
  for i in range(10):
    value[str(i)] = i
  value['J'] = 10
  value['Q'] = 10
  value['K'] = 10
  value['A'] = 11
  value['T'] = 10

  score = sum(int(value[card[0]]) for card in player_hand)
  if score > 21:

    # Adjust for Aces
    adjustment = sum(10 if card[0]=='A' else 0 for card in player_hand)
    score -= adjustment



  return score

#ask about this

def show_result(player_hand):

    player_score = int(score_hand(player_hand))

    if player_score > 21:
        print('*** Player Bust! ***')
    elif player_score == 21:
        print('*** Blackjack! Player Wins! ***')


##else:
##            push(player_hand,dealer_hand)
##def push(player_score,dealers_score):
##    print("Dealer and Player tie! It's a push.")        
##else:
##    // Logic to continue game





def hit_stand(show_hand,player_hand):

    while True:
      x = input("Would you like to Hit or Stand? Enter 'h' or 's'")

      if x[0].lower() == 'h':
           hit(show_hand,player_hand)  # hit() function defined above

      elif x[0].lower() == 's':
           print("Player stands. Dealer is playing.")
           playing = False









def show_hand(player_hand):

  score_hand(player_hand)
  score = f"Player's hand is {score_hand(player_hand)}: "
  cards = ' | '.join([f"{names[card[0]]} of {suits[card[1]]}" for card in player_hand])

  return score + cards





for hand in hands:
  print(show_hand(player_hand))
  show_result(player_hand)




#Stage 3 - Testing purpose only       (DEALERS HAND)

### Deal first card
card = playing_cards.deal_one_card()
### Append it to the player_hand list
dealers_hand.append(card)
### Deal second card
card = playing_cards.deal_one_card()
### Append it to the player_hand list
dealers_hand.append(card)
### Display the player's hand to the screen using a simple print statement


#Stage 4 and 5

def score_hand(dealers_hand):
  " Scores hand with adjustment for Ace "
  value = {}
  for i in range(10):
    value[str(i)] = i
  value['J'] = 10
  value['Q'] = 10
  value['K'] = 10
  value['A'] = 11
  value['T'] = 10

  score = sum(int(value[card[0]]) for card in dealers_hand)
  if score > 21:
    # Adjust for Aces
    adjustment = sum(10 if card[0]=='A' else 0 for card in dealers_hand)
    score -= adjustment

  return score

#ask about this

def show_result(dealers_hand):

    dealers_score = int(score_hand(dealers_hand))

    if dealers_score > 21:
        print('*** Dealer Bust! ***')
    elif dealers_score == 21:
        print('*** Blackjack! Dealer Wins! ***')


def show_hand(dealers_hand):

  score = f"Dealers's hand is {score_hand(dealers_hand)}: "
  cards = ' | '.join([f"{names[card[0]]} of {suits[card[1]]}" for card in dealers_hand])

  return score + cards


for hand in hands:
  print(show_hand(dealers_hand))
  print('')
  show_result(dealers_hand)
  hit_stand(show_hand, player_hand)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import random

Dealer_Cards=[]
Player_Cards=[] # im also beginner in programming just little know some C from College
Total_Player=0   # and watched some tutorial like 5 min and get the whole algorithm 
                  # then start thinking and coding i have little excuse like how to i
Total_Dealer=0    # stop when player or dealer hit >=21 expect option .
#Deal the cards
#Dealer Cards
while len(Dealer_Cards) != 2:
    Dealer_Cards.append(random.randint(1,11))
    if len(Dealer_Cards) == 2:
        print("Dealer has ",Dealer_Cards)

# Player Cards
while len(Player_Cards) != 2:
    Player_Cards.append(random.randint(1,11))
    if len(Player_Cards) == 2:
        print("You have ",Player_Cards)
        print("you have 2 option Hit or Stay:[Click '1' for Hit and if you want to Stay click '0']:")
        option= int(input(""))
        if option == 0:
            Total_Dealer+= sum(Dealer_Cards) #Dealer_Cards= i
            print("sum of the Dealer cards:",Total_Dealer)
            Total_Player+= sum(Player_Cards) # Player_Cards= x
            print("sum of the Player cards:",Total_Player)

            if Total_Dealer > Total_Player:
                print("Dealer Wons")
                break
            elif Total_Player > Total_Dealer:
                print("You Won")
                break
            else:
                print("Scoreless.")
                break

        elif option == 1:
            while len(Player_Cards) != 3:
                Player_Cards.append(random.randint(1,11))
                Dealer_Cards.append(random.randint(1,11))
        if len(Player_Cards) == 3:
            print("You have ",Player_Cards)
            print("you have 2 option Hit or Stay:[Click '1' for Stay and if you want to Stay click '0']")
            option= int(input(""))
            if option== 0:
                Total_Dealer += sum(Dealer_Cards)
                print("sum of the Dealer cards:", Total_Dealer)
                Total_Player += sum(Player_Cards)
                print("sum of the Player cards:", Total_Player)

                if Total_Player > 21 and Total_Dealer <= 21:
                    print("You are BUSTED !")
                    break
                elif Total_Player == Total_Dealer:
                    print("Scoreless")
                    break
                elif Total_Player <= 21 and Total_Dealer > 21:
                    print("You WON !")
                    break
                elif (Total_Player < 21 and Total_Dealer < 21) and (Total_Player > Total_Dealer):
                    print("You WON !")
                elif (Total_Player < 21 and Total_Dealer < 21) and (Total_Dealer > Total_Player):
                    print("Dealer WON !")
                    break
            elif option == 1:
                while len(Player_Cards) != 4:
                    Player_Cards.append(random.randint(1,11))
                    Dealer_Cards.append(random.randint(1,11))
        if len(Player_Cards) == 4:
            print("You have ",Player_Cards)
            print("you have 2 option Hit or Stay:[Click '1' for Stay and if you want to Stay click '0']")
            option= int(input(""))
            if option == 0:
                Total_Dealer += sum(Dealer_Cards)
                print("sum of the Dealer cards:", Total_Dealer)
                Total_Player += sum(Player_Cards)
                print("sum of the Player cards:", Total_Player)

                if Total_Player > 21 and Total_Dealer <= 21:
                    print("You are BUSTED !")
                    break
                elif Total_Player == Total_Dealer:
                    print("Scoreless")
                    break
                elif Total_Player <= 21 and Total_Dealer > 21:
                    print("You WON !")
                    break
                elif (Total_Player < 21 and Total_Dealer < 21) and (Total_Player > Total_Dealer):
                    print("You WON !")
                    break
                elif (Total_Player < 21 and Total_Dealer < 21) and (Total_Dealer > Total_Player):
                    print("Dealer WON !")
                    break
            elif option == 1:
                while len(Player_Cards) != 5:
                    Player_Cards.append(random.randint(1, 11))
                    Dealer_Cards.append(random.randint(1,11))
                    if len(Player_Cards) == 5:
                        print("You have ",Player_Cards)
                        Total_Dealer+= sum(Dealer_Cards)
                        print("sum of the Dealer cards:",Total_Dealer)
                        Total_Player+= sum(Player_Cards)
                        print("sum of the Player cards:",Total_Player)
                        if Total_Player > 21 and Total_Dealer <= 21:
                            print("You are BUSTED !")
                            break
                        elif Total_Player == Total_Dealer:
                            print("Scoreless")
                            break
                        elif Total_Player <= 21 and Total_Dealer > 21:
                            print("You WON !")
                            break
                        elif (Total_Player < 21 and Total_Dealer < 21) and (Total_Player > Total_Dealer):
                            print("You WON !")
                            break
                        elif (Total_Player < 21 and Total_Dealer < 21) and (Total_Dealer > Total_Player):
                            print("Dealer WON !")
                            break
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will get you on the right track (I couldn't find a 'hit' function defined, so you can do all the work right in hit_stand, as follows):

```
def hit_stand(show_hand,player_hand):

    while True:
      x = input("Would you like to Hit or Stand? Enter 'h' or 's'")

      if x[0].lower() == 'h':
           player_hand.append(playing_cards.deal_one_card())

      elif x[0].lower() == 's':
           print("Player stands. Dealer is playing.")
           playing = False
```

That will solve how the player hits, but I didn't see logic in your code for the dealer to decide to hit or stand, which are based on standard house rules.

Comment: Thanks for the help random, yeh i know my code is all over the place. im just trying to get the hit function working even though the game may be kinda a mess. Any suggestions on if its even possible for me to add another card ontop.

I used your part to help deal with the hit defined but what would i do to actually update the total and display the third card ?

Comment: Another problem I notice with your approach is that you have, for example, show_hand or score_hand defined twice, one with a player_hand variable and one with dealer_hand variable, but that isn't how it works. Rather you only need one show_hand and one score_hand defined, and it accepts a parameter that you pass it from the outside and you pass in either player_hand or dealer_hand